# Locally served javascript not running

Tags: javascript, go

So I have a js file called sankey.js that has this content -

```
console.log("HELLO WORLD");
```

I load it in an index.html file that looks like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javacript" src="sankey.js"></script>
<script type="text/javacript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1> TEST </h1>
</body>
```

This is served by a golang webserver - the rest of the code is in this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900727/cannot-find-local-script-resource-with-golang-server/30901320#30901320

I successful find the file, but the console.log does not show.

Why?

I even added a debugger, like this

```
debugger;
console.log("HELLO WORLD");
```

And that is not run.

Comment: Try prefixing the `src` with a `/`, `src="/sankey.js"`

Comment: Can you load the script directly? `http://localhost:8888/sankey.js` ??

Comment: Yes. I can except at localhost:8100. I added a random string, in the hopes that I would get an error

debugger
console.log("HELLO WORLD");
dfdfd

but nothing, it's like the browser doesn't know that this is a javascript file, and it's treating it like text

Comment: Nope - changes I make locally are being updated. Could it be how I'm serving the index.html?

Comment: Is there a way for javascript to be served such that it is being treated like a text file?

Comment: Have you tried placing the <script> tag just before the closing </body> tag?

Comment: Just tried that, no dice.

Comment: This has happened to me before. Make sure that the javascript file is being served with the correct content type (e.g. `application/javascript`).

Comment: (the web inspector should show this - status, accept-encoding, type, etc.)

Comment: @TimCooper, what do you mean? So right now I'm serving html that has script tags, what should the content type be?

Comment: Ok. So looking at the Headers for sankey.js, I see that the Content-Type is application.javascript and there's a 200 status code

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on having a similar problem when I wrote my own basic web server using Go (golang) was that I got the paths to the file mixed so it was getting `404 Not Found`.

I recomend using the Network tab in Chrome debug (F12) to check that the `sankey.js` is actually being served to the browser.

Comment: it is being served - I see that sankey.js exists under sources, and the request for it has a 200 response

Comment: Great, then I agree with @toshiomagic and suggest that you add a break point in your javascript.

Comment: So I added a debugger, and it doesn't trigger

Comment: Is the js served with a content type header ?